# Overpass API query: Get streets in city limited to a particular country

Tags: openstreetmap, query, overpass-api, city

I am working with a self-installed version of the Overpass API.

I need to be able to query all street names in a particular city, Inverness in the United Kingdom (GB).  There is also a city called Inverness in Florida, United States.

Therefore I need a query which limits the results returned to Inverness in GB.

This is the query that I have tried but it returns an empty result set.

```
[out:json]; 
(area["ISO3166-1"="GB"][admin_level=2]; )->.country;
(area["name"="Inverness"])->.city;
(way(country)(city)[highway]; ); 
(._;>;);
out;
```

How can I reformulate the query to return the information that I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [Inverness node](https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/21063119) suggests that it isn't in GB (it isn't really an admin unit).

```
is_in   Highland;Scotland;United Kingdom;Europe
is_in:continent Europe
is_in:country   Scotland
is_in:iso_3166_2    SCT
is_in:province  United Kingdom
name    Inverness
```

So I would try something like:

```
[out:json]; 
(area["ISO3166-2"="GB-SCT"][admin_level=4]; )->.country;
(area["name"="Inverness"])->.city;
(way(country)(city)[highway]; ); 
(._;>;);
out;
```

Comment: Actually it *is* in [GB](https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/62149). Please note that most OSM keys are lowercase, so `Country` should be `country` instead. However, [Scotland](https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/58446) has `admin_level=4` (see [admin_level values for specific countries](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:boundary%3Dadministrative#10_admin_level_values_for_specific_countries)) and no `Country` key set. Better query for `area["ISO3166-2"="GB-SCT"][admin_level=4]`.

Answer (score 1):

Your query syntax looks wrong. Try the following instead:

```
[out:json];
area["ISO3166-1"="GB"][admin_level=2]->.country;
area["name"="Inverness"]->.city;
way(area.country)(area.city)[highway];
(._;>;);
out;
```

Although I'm not sure if this query is ideal for your task or if it can be optimized.